# angular display status_text differently on local vs prod

Tags: django, angular, google-cloud-run

I have a simple login method in angular that calls the service API and I want to display the error to the alert service. However, the response parsed from the server is not same local vs prod in cloud environment.

```
this.authService
  .login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe({
    next: () => {
      // get return url from query parameters or default to home page
      this.alertService.success("Login successful");
      const returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
      this.router.navigateByUrl(returnUrl);
    },
    error: (error) => {
      this.alertService.error(error);
      this.loading = false;
    },
  });
```

this works well locally the response shows

```
{
"headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null
},
"status": 401,
"statusText": "Unauthorized",
"url": "http://localhost:4200/api/v1/token/",
"ok": false,
"name": "HttpErrorResponse",
"message": "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/v1/token/: 401 Unauthorized",
"error": {
    "type": "client_error",
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "no_active_account",
            "detail": "No active account found with the given credentials",
            "attr": null
        }
    ]
}
```

however, in prod it is giving me different statusText somehow

```
{
"headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null
},
"status": 401,
"statusText": "OK",
"url": "https://remoteurl-cloudrun-app/api/v1/token/",
"ok": false,
"name": "HttpErrorResponse",
"message": "Http failure response for https://run.app/api/v1/token/: 401 OK",
"error": {
    "type": "client_error",
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "no_active_account",
            "detail": "No active account found with the given credentials",
            "attr": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't understand why. Has anyone experienced this before?
FYI, the backend is Django using simple-jwt, everything is in default no customization.

Comment: Hi, It seems that you're getting a 401 status, have you checked Cloud Run's public [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#401)?

Comment: this is an expected 401 error from Django. I'm just not sure why the response could be different local vs cloud. Anyway, I just worked around it.

Comment: Would you be willing to share the work around you found for this issue? I think it would be helpful to others who may encounter the same problem in the future.

Comment: oh, i just ignored that statusText field, and a custom exception that only read the status_code, message and errors